# Firebase - get document by id in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a beginner so i'm a little confused.

I have a list of books, i get all of the data there.

```
...
const booksCollectionRef = collection(db, "books");
const data = await getDocs(booksCollectionRef);
const filteredData = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
  ...doc.data(),
  id: doc.id,
}));
 ...
```

But i want to click on one item on the list to get the data from that specific book.

```
...
const docRef = doc(db, "books", "idOfThatBook");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
console.log(docSnap.data());
...
```

With this i only get data from book with that id. How can i get data from any book i click on?

Thank you.

Comment: You will need to track the IDs of all books that you show, and then (when the user clicks on that book) pass that to the code that loads the data. This seems a good example to start from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44325369/209103